# Upload image using iOS Swift

Tags: ios, rest, swift, upload, jersey

I am attempting to upload a image to my jersey server. This is my Swift code:

```
var url:NSURL = NSURL.URLWithString("http://www.quentinroussat.fr/assets/img/iOS%20icon's%20Style/ios8.png")
    var payload:NSData = NSData.dataWithContentsOfURL(url, options: nil, error: nil)


    var err: NSError?
    var imageData :NSData = NSData.dataWithContentsOfURL(url,options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: &err)


    let endpoint: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:8080/rest/service/Upload")
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: endpoint)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"


    // set Content-Type in HTTP header
    let boundaryConstant = "----------V2ymHFg03esomerandomstuffhbqgZCaKO6jy";
    let contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundaryConstant
    request.HTTPBody = imageData

     request.addValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
     request.addValue("multipart/form-data", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")


    var response: NSURLResponse? = nil
    var error: NSError? = nil

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().uploadTaskWithRequest(request, fromData: imageData, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

         println(request)
         println(response)
        // println(payload)

    })
    task.resume()
```

Here is my Jersey service:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/Upload")
public Response fileUpload(
        @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileInfo)
        throws IOException
{
     final String FILE_UPLOAD_PATH = "/Users/Luke/Documents/Temp/Uploads";


    Response.Status respStatus = Response.Status.OK;

    if (fileInfo == null)
    {
        respStatus = Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
    }
    else
    {
        final String fileName = fileInfo.getFileName();
        String uploadedFileLocation = FILE_UPLOAD_PATH + File.separator
                + fileName;

        try
        {
            saveToDisc(uploadedInputStream, uploadedFileLocation);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            respStatus = Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return Response.status(respStatus).build();
}
```

I know the service works as I can upload via a standard html page, however, via the simulator nothing hits the rest end point. I am obviously new to swift so any pointers would be appreciated.

Here is the request / response from the simulator:

```
    <NSMutableURLRequest: 0x79674830> { URL: http://localhost:8080/rest/service/Upload, headers: {
Accept = "multipart/form-data";
"Content-Type" = "multipart/form-data; boundary=----------V2ymHFg03esomerandomstuffhbqgZCaKO6jy";
```

} }

```
<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7871efa0> { URL: http://localhost:8080/rest/service/Upload } { status code: 406, headers {
"Content-Length" = 0;
Date = "Sun, 28 Sep 2014 07:20:25 GMT";
Server = "Apache-Coyote/1.1";
```

} }

Comment: how do you fix it?